# How can I implement tooltips for Rickshaw legends?

Tags: javascript, time-series, tooltip, legend, rickshaw

I'm using Rickshaw to display a graph of several time series with a legend. I would like to display some text when the user hovers the mouse cursor over an entry in the legend. There is apparently no built-in way to do this in Rickshaw. I assume I can iterate over what the `Rickshaw.Graph.Legend()` constructor returns and add title attributes, but the details elude me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out on my own. Here are the essentials, without error checking, etc.:

```
var legend = new Rickshaw.Graph.Legend( {
    graph: _graph,
    element: document.getElementById('legend')
} );

var nodes = legend.element.firstChild.getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var li in nodes)
    nodes[li].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].title = "I'm a tooltip!".
```